# Partial derivatives - polyniomial

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I need help proving that each mapping $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R} \ : \ f_a(y):= (a,y), \ f_b (x):=(x,b)$ are polynomials, is a polynomial with two variables.

It is obvious that partial derivatives of a polynomial are polynomials, but I don't know how to deduce that the function must be a polynomial if the partial derivatives are polynomials.

Could you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain your notation a bit more? Are the $f_a, f_b$ the partials? What are $(a,y),(x,b)$?

Comment: @Roses: Do you mean $f_a(y) := f(a, y)$ and similar for $f_b$?

Comment: Yes, they are partials. Frankly speaking, I couldn't understand this notation, so I thought you might. I agree with John - it would make more sense if $f_a(y)=f(a,y)$. Thanks.

Comment: Could you help me solve it? I still don't see how to prove that.

Comment: By the fact for a function f:R→R if the derivative is polynomial then f is polynomial.

Comment: Ok, but for a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ it's fairly easy to guess what the original function looks like, knowing what the derivative is. For example if $f' = ax^5 + ... dx + e$, then $f = \frac{a}{6} x^6 + ...$. But it seems more complicated for two variables.

Comment: First, consider f as a function of x (with parameter y) what you get? Then consider f as a function of y (with parameter x)...

Comment: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a} (y) = f(a,y)$ and $f(a,y)$ is a polynomial with variable $y$. Similarly the other derivative is a polynomial with variable $x$. But could you tell me how to "construct" the original function from these derivatives? We can't just multiply both derivatives by $x$ and $y$ respectively and divide the coefficients and then add them, can we?